# `authenticate` filter never gets called

Tags: filters, authentication

I've added and network activated a plugin with this code:

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'my_authenticate', 1000, 2);

function my_authenticate($user, $username){

    // We never arrive in this function
```

From a debugger I can see that we hit the `add_filter` line but we never enter the `my_authenticate` function.

Why's that?

And how do I fix the problem?

Comment: What do you mean "never arrive"? What is this "debugger" you are using?

Comment: When do you expect this filter to fire? What are you doing to test it?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic xdebug.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'd expect it to fire between the time the user clicks Login and the time they see the Dashboard.

Comment: And you are doing what to test it?

Comment: There's a redirect between login & seeing the dashboard - unless you're using debug *logs*, you won't see anything.

Comment: @s_ha_dum 1. put a breakpoint on the add_filter. 2. put a breakpoint in the function being called. 3. login to WordPress. The breakpoint from point 1 gets hit but the breakpoint from 2 never gets hit and WordPress proceeds to the dashboard. I was hoping I'd overlooked something obvious and avoid stepping into WordPress Core Code.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few possibilities, though there certainly could be more.

1. On successful login there is a redirect to the dashboard meaning
   that if you expect to see something output by that function, you
   won't. Try this:

   ```
   add_filter('authenticate', 'my_authenticate', 1000, 2);

   function my_authenticate($user, $username){
     var_dump($user, $username);
     die;
     // We never arrive in this function
     return $user;
   }
   ```

   Login, and you should see output. Remove the `die` and you won't see
   anything because the output is wiped out by the redirect, in a
   sense.
2. [The `authenticate` filter is inside a pluggable function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src//wp-includes/pluggable.php#L567), so it
   is possible that that function has been replaced by the theme or a by a plugin and that filter
   is actually not being called.
3. You are running your filter late so some earlier filter could
   (though it would be bad form in my opinion) be interrupting things
   before your callback gets a chance to fire-- `remove_all_filters()`
   for example.